# Why people don't use sequential numbers for image storage?

Tags: php, database, image, server-side

I've been looking around and I've seen that, for example, instagram uses big strings for naming their images (instagram/p/BB-cCvtje4k, for example), and so does facebook. Is there any cons of naming the picture like thisuser/1, and the next picture thisuser/2 and so on? Or is it bad practice doing something like the following on my server side code?

```
$i=1;
while(file_exists('thisuser/'.$i)) {
    i++;
}
$image_path = 'thisuser/'.$i;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Biggest con.... people can just keep incrementing the number to access every image on your site, whether you want them to or not

Comment: That's a good one. But I think it's safer to make an image private using code than hiding it's path. If you don't want someone to see an image just make it avaiable for the users you want it to be. Facebook does it. Not sure if instagram does though, but I think so. So I don't think that's their reason for not doing it this way.

Comment: My comment isn't simply "security through obscurity", it's quite a common practise simply to eliminate the temptation to try; you should always still validate within your code anyway

Comment: Using UUID values also makes it easier to merge databases or transfer data from one database to another, whereas sequential pk numbers are likely to need resetting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cons of using base 10 digit characters for sites at the scale of instagram or facebook is that the URL would probably be way too long. Keep in mind that facebook receives something like **1 billion new photo uploads per week**. So that's a lot of digits. Using something like a base 36 alphabet may reduce the character count. At that scale efficiency matters on multiple fronts.

However, what you're probably not taking into consideration is that there is a very distinct design behind those URLs and what they mean and it has nothing to do with sequential or non-sequential numbers.

For example, according to one of [Facebook's white papers](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Beaver.pdf) on their **Finding a needle in Haystack: Facebook's photo storage**, they point out that the URL is composed as such `http://(CDN)/(Cache)/(Machine id)/(Logical volume, Photo)` where each part of the URL represents a distinct physical/logical identifier that pin-points where in their photo storage mechanism the photo can be retrieved from.

> When a user visits a page the web server uses the Directory
>   to construct a URL for each photo. The URL
>   contains several pieces of information, each piece corresponding
>   to the sequence of steps from when a user’s
>   browser contacts the CDN (or Cache) to ultimately retrieving
>   a photo from a machine in the Store. A typical
>   URL that directs the browser to the CDN looks like the
>   following:
>   `http://(CDN)/(Cache)/(Machine id)/(Logical volume, Photo)`

Comment: So there isn't obligatory cons for using sequencial naming, and they just use their way because it suits them better?

Comment: Right, this design helps them uniquely identify the photos on their massive storage system. Certainly, very few people on this earth have the problems or design requirements of sites like facebook. If you were relying on your MySQL database to supply an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value as the PK that uniquely identifies the photos on your storage system there is nothing inherently wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

Sherif's answer describes the problem well. In short this totally depends on what you are expecting - how many images there will be in total or per day, whether you will be using them to display it back to the user.

Example if there are going to be large number of images uploaded daily, you can segregate folders year/month/day/-image_name.img-, where image-name can be a random uuid.
For small number of files, and when you do not care if a user is able to access a image he isn't supposed to, sequential number naming is just fine.